# Getting status as "Time trigger not satisfied" when preview scheduled endeca content

Tags: endeca, endeca-workbench

I am facing an issue when previewing the scheduled content in endeca XM, When i am clicking on the audit button on preview page it shows me a table where i can see the status of the scheduled content as "Time trigger not satisfied". And so i am not able see the scheduled content.

Any idea what is going wrong here. Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue, this issue was related EndecaPreview layer component not in effect.